# SQL using Index when hardcoded, but not when using a subselect

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-optimization

I want to select all data in a table t which has a specific name as column entry. Table t has an index on the column name.

When I execute the specifying the names hardcoded in the where clause, then the index is used and the results are calculated super fast.

But when I do use a join with another (small) table, then the index is not used and it is super slow.

Hardcoded:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE date = xyz
AND name in ('hardcoded_name_1','hardcoded_name_2', ...)
AND status = 1;
```

Join i really want to do:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT name2 from t2) on name = name2
WHERE date = xyz
AND status = 1;
```

Here the table t is large and table t2 is very small.

Execution plan of the join:

```
SELECT STATEMENT ALL_ROWS 
  4 NESTED LOOPS 
    2 PARTITION RANGE ALL 
      1 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE t.name 
  3 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) t2.name
```

Comment: provide the execution plan as well but it for sure , name2 in t2 is not a fk to name column and putting index on that even won't help , and that's why it's slow probabaly untill we take a look at the execution plan

Comment: Oracle prefers the predicates on `date` and `status` over `name`. If `date` and `status` really narrow down the result set more than `name` would, then it is correct. But if `name` would narrow it down more, then you want ot reverse the join order so that it starts with `t2` and then joins to `t1`

Comment: hi eshirvana. I added the execution plan in the main post.

Comment: Hi Paul. I tried to do the join in the reverse order, also tried left/right join but unfortunatlely it does not help in terms of performance.

Comment: I don't mean simply reverse the order in your SQL, I mean use statistics or indexing or hinting to get the plan to reverse its order. You can't do that simply by rearranging the SQL itself. Others are giving you some reasonable advice, so I'll let them help you further on this. I'm just explaining what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

You want to select rows matching a list of names. In the extremes, it can happen that no row matches any of the names or that all rows match.

In the first query, the optimizer knows exactly how many and which names to look up. This helps it deciding how many matches to expect. Moreover, you are using an `IN` clause, so even if there are duplicate values in the list, the main table's rows will only get selected once. The optimizer considers it the fastest way to do this using an index.

In the second query you changed two things:

1. You have replaced the hard-coded values with a select. The DBMS must now know the t2 table in order to estimate how many matches to expect. Are there statistics on the table? Are they up-to-date? Just running through the entire table instead of using an index sounds like a good approach to get to a stable run time.
2. You have replaced the `IN` clause with a join. This means, theoretically you can get t rows multifold in the results. Only if there is a unique key on t2.name2 will the DBMS see it guaranteed that there can't be any duplicates.

I don't know why you switched to a join. Do you need a join? Is there any data you want to select from t2? As is, it looks like you still only need a look up:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE date = xyz
AND name in (SELECT name2 from t2)
AND status = 1;
```

Then, you may want to gather statistics on both tables again, ideally with a histogram on the name columns, so the DBMS knows enough about your tables to get to the best execution plan.

The most appropriate index for the query seems to be something like

```
create index idx1 on t (date, name, status);
```

or maybe

```
create index idx2 on t (name, status, date);
```

or some other index with these three columns. The index should have the columns in order of their selectivity. What percentage of the rows do you get for one name? What percentage of the rows do you get for one date? What percentage of the rows do you get for status 1? The smaller the percentage, the more selective the column. Make the most selective column the first in the index.

Comment: Hi Thorsten. Thank you for your comprehensive answer.

First of all you are right - I do not need a join in this case, but I also tried the select with the subquery and the execution time is roughly the same as with the join.

Unfortunately I cannot change the index of table t. Table t is a really big table and table t2 is very small, having only 30 rows or so. So ideally I want to tell Oracle:
1. Take all the names  from t2 which are only a few and then 
2. Take those few names and select the corresponding columns in t

Comment: I don't understand why you can't add an index on t. And have you gathered statistics, so that Oracle knows how small t2 is and that there are just a few names in it? What percentage of t rows match the names in t2?

Comment: I cannot change the index because I have only read grants on t. How can I gather these statistics? All names of t2 are included in t. t2 has 40 rows. With the where statement applied to t, t includes roughly 400.000. The match is mostly on 40 rows of t. So 0.00001=0.001% of all rows in t are matched by the names in t2.

Comment: So, yes, if Oracle knew its tables, it should use the index. Here is the docs on `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68582. You can even use the `method_opt` parameter to get a frequency histogram on the name column. Hope this helps finding some examples.

Comment: I will try that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `subquery` which causes the optimizer might not to be able to use the index efficiently. Because it somehow is similar to having a temporary table that has no relation to the first table.

To improve the performance, you need to use direct joining like:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
JOIN t2 ON t.name = t2.name2
WHERE date = xyz AND status = 1;
```

Also, make sure you have fk which help your join to become faster.

Comment: Hello Ali Malek. Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the query is equally slow as the other join. I have discovered that t2.name2 is also an index which i see is used in the execution plan.

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan ( or SQL Monitor report) from the two executions.

Comment: This is the execution plan of the join:

SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS
4 NESTED LOOPS  
2 PARTITION RANGE ALL  
1 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE t.name 
3 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) t2.name

Answer (score 0):

Try using some hints:

```
SELECT /*+ leading(t2) use_nl(t) index(t ix_t_name) */ t.*
FROM table t
JOIN t2 on name = name2
WHERE date = xyz AND status = 1
```

;

There ix_t_name is the actual name of that index.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it did not make my query faster

Comment: It would be useful to see the full output of the execution plan including the estimated cardinality. Meanwhile, can you try a hash join...  SELECT /*+ leading(t2) use_hash(t) */ t.*
FROM table t
JOIN t2 on name = name2
WHERE date = xyz AND status = 1